# Drawing lines in loop

Tags: java

How to draw horizontal lines between those four lines and have same space between them like on image.

[image]

DrawPanel.java:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        int pieces = 5;
        
        g.drawLine(0, height/2, width/2, 0);
        g.drawLine(width/2, 0, width, height/2);
        g.drawLine(0, height, width/2, height/2);
        g.drawLine(width/2, height/2, width, height);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < pieces; i++) {
            int y = height * i/pieces;
            
            if (y > height / 2)
                g.drawLine(0, y, width / 2, y);
        }
    }
}
```

DrawPanelTest.java:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawPanelTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel); 
        application.setSize(1280,720); 
        application.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

What i've got so far:

[image: IMAGE2]

how to make those lines in bottom left corner fit between lines not in the for loop (something like show above)?

Comment: If you look at your first image, you need to draw 5 lines over "half the height of your panel, starting mid-way down". So start there: your code currently starts at the right height, but draws too many lines, spaced too closely together, and draws them too thin. So fix that first. Then, note that as you go from "mid height" to "full height", the line gets shorter, so you can't draw each line "the same", you need to make sure its second x coordinate is different at each iteration.

Comment: 1) It looks like you've got it right for the "triangles".  2) Your arithmetic is wrong for the lines.  I'm sure you'll figure it out.  3) As far as "hiding the lines under the triangles", you've got several choices: a) Draw x1..x2 on the left, then x3..x4 on the right,  ... OR ... b) draw the triangle twice: first as a "fill" (hide the lines underneath), then again as "lines" (like you're doing now): https://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/shapesandfills/

Answer (score 0):

You could draw the bottom triangle to overwrite the lines, or you can calculate the distance away from the center that you need to start/end drawing the lines.

Since we know the height and width of the triangle (half the pyramid) you can calculate the top angle.  Once you know the top angle, you can use that to calculate the width of the bottom side at each iteration of the line.

```
public class PyramidLinesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        JFrame application = new JFrame();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.add(panel); 
        application.setSize(1280,720); 
        application.setVisible(true); 
    }

    static class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            int pieces = 5;           
            
            drawPyramids(g, width, height);
            drawLines(g, width, height, pieces);            
        }
        
        private void drawPyramids(Graphics g, int width, int height) {
            g.drawLine(0, height/2, width/2, 0);
            g.drawLine(width/2, 0, width, height/2);
            g.drawLine(0, height, width/2, height/2);
            g.drawLine(width/2, height/2, width, height);
        }
        
        private void drawLines(Graphics g, int width, int height, int pieces) {
            // Determine the size of the side and bottom (adjacent and opposite)        
            double halfY = height / 2;
            double halfW = width / 2;                  
            
            // Tan = O / A
            // Tan = halfW / halfY
            double tanTheta = halfW / halfY;
            double theta = Math.atan(tanTheta); // Radians Math.toDegrees()
            double dist = halfY / pieces;
            
            for (int i = 0; i < pieces; i++) {
                // Start at halfY and move down by I distance
                int y = (int) (halfY + (i * dist));

                // Calculate the distance away from halfX using theta
                // tan(theta) = O / A
                // O = tan(theta) * A
                int fromHalfW = (int) (Math.tan(theta) * (i * dist));

                // Draw the lines accordingly
                g.drawLine(0, y, (int) (halfW - fromHalfW), y);
                g.drawLine((int) (halfW + fromHalfW), y, width, y);
            }
        }
    }
}
```